# How do i write an R scripts that will create an object "l" below:

Tags: r

This is the output I want it to give. I have tried several options but it doesn't work.

```
> l
 $item1
[1] 1 2 3
$item2
[1] "a"
$item3
[1] TRUE FALSE TRUE
$item4
[1] 2.5 4.2
```

Comment: What did you try, and how exactly didn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l = list(item1 = c(1,2,3), item2 = 'a', item3 = c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE), item4 = c(2.5,4.2))
```

Be aware that all the items are of different datatypes.